# NSNotificationCenter not acting on the message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In one of my classes I post a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ALERTNOTI" object:self userInfo:nil];
```

In my app delegaate I listen:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod) name:@"ALERTNOTI" object:nil];
```

I use `NSLog` to track when I send and when the method `myMethod` gets called.

The method is not getting called despite me sending out the notification.

Is there something that I need to know about `NSNotification`? Is it tempermental?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 do this changes

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ALERTNOTI" object:nil];

   if you want to pass some object through the notification. then do this
    ex: you want to pass an NSDictionary *dict

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ALERTNOTI" object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

the method you want to call via notification should be like this.

```
  -(void)method:(NSNotification *) notif
   {
      // your code here.

      //if you want to access your dict
       NSDictionary *myDict=[notif userInfo];



   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ALERTNOTI" object:nil];
```